# Akka: Exception not being logged in test ActorSystem

Tags: java, akka

I am attempting to unit test my Java Akka actor using the test kit

```
public class AggregationActor extends UntypedActor {
    final private LoggingAdapter logger = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);
    private final ActorRef mergeActor;
    private final ActorRef saveActor;
    private final AggregationHelper aggregationHelper;
```

This AggregationActor contains some dependencies which I am passing in through the constructor

I am using TestProbes to mock the ActorRefs and EasyMock to mock the AggregationHelper

My AggregationActorTest unit test contains the following

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.apply();
    mergeActor = new TestProbe(actorSystem);
    saveActor =  new TestProbe(actorSystem);
    aggregationHelper = EasyMock.createMock(AggregationHelper.class);
    aggregationActor = TestActorRef.apply(Props.create(AggregationActor.class, mergeActor.ref(), saveActor.ref(), aggregationHelper), actorSystem);
}

@Test
public void mySampleTest() throws Exception {
    reset(aggregationHelper);
    // Set expectations on the aggregationHelper
    replay(blockToTicketMapHelper);
    aggregationActor.tell(new AggregationVO();
    saveActor.expectMsg(new SaveVO());        
}
```

What I am finding is that if my AggregationActor.onReceive() throws an exception then this is not logged, or I don't see it thrown up through the stack

I only get: `java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg`

How do I set up my test ActorSystem such that any exceptions are not suppressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `TestActorRef#receive` method as described in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/testing.html#The_Way_In-Between__Expecting_Exceptions). Using this method instead of `tell` ensures that any thrown exceptions don't get swallowed by the TestActorRef.

For example:

```
@Test
public void mySampleTest() throws Exception {
    reset(aggregationHelper);
    // Set expectations on the aggregationHelper
    replay(blockToTicketMapHelper);
    aggregationActor.receive(new AggregationVO();
    saveActor.expectMsg(new SaveVO());        
}
```